# Question on how to accumulate a spread in TradingViw

Tags: tradingview-api

In my custom indicator in TradingView, I am looking to accumulate the spread between J and L (see below) since the start of a security -

```
      MBTP = ((high - srcd) + (srcd - low)) / srcd

      J = ema(MBTP,150)
      L = ema(MBTP,200)
      N = (J - L)

      d = ta.cum(O)
```

I keep receiving the following error.
1:22:10 PM  Error at 46:0 Could not find function or function reference 'ta.cum'.

What other script do I need to complete have the ta.cum work properly?

Thank you
Tim